# Having trouble 'segueing' from one view controller to another, getting weird warnings

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am getting a very strange error. I think the compiler is trying to tell me that it can't segue to another **view controller** until it is done executing all the code in my current **view controller** but I am not sure.

I'm literally getting input by using an alert box (i.e. calling a function called `generateTextField`).

Then when I am done I'm saying "Hey I want you to go to another view controller" - but the the compiler instead tells me "Hey I don't think so".

Here is my error:

***Warning: Attempt to present HairStyle1ViewController: 0x7...>  on browseBarbersViewController: 0x7...> which is already presenting 
 Warning: Attempt to present HairStyle1ViewController: 0x7..>  on browseBarbersViewController: 0x7...> which is already presenting***

```
@IBAction func AddNewStyleButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        // Get the "hairstyle name" from the user
        generateTextField();

        // OK We are done with that function, now transition to the
        // next screen
        performSegueWithIdentifier("HairStyle1", sender: self);
    }



    // Generate a text field for user input (i.e. call the alert function)
    func generateTextField()
    {

        //1. Create the alert controller.
        var tempStyle = "";
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add a New Style", message: "Enter the name of the new hairstyle below", preferredStyle: .Alert);


        //2. Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Your New Hairstyle Goes Here..";
        })

        //3. Grab the value from the text field, and print it when the user clicks OK.
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
            tempStyle = textField.text!;
            print("New Style Added is: " + tempStyle);
            HairStyle = tempStyle;

        }))

        // 4. Present the alert.
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

It's also weird that when I take out the `generateTextField()` function it performs the segue perfectly. I'm very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, I figured it out. I had to instead, segue in the body of the alert function.

I fixed this by adding

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("HairStyle1", sender: self);
```

after the

`HairStyle = tempStyle;` line

Comment: Yes i Checked it and it work fine .follow Yusha Points it will work fine.